# Are adverbs like "basically", "really", "definitely" wordy in essay writing?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, writing

I use [Grammarly](https://app.grammarly.com/) to help my writing. I notice that whenever I use adverbs like "basically", "really", "definitely", Grammarly will say these words are unnecessary, wordy and suggest removing them, e.g.

1. **Basically**, they lost because they did not bother to practice. Grammarly will suggest removing the word **Basically** and just write *They lost because they did not bother to practice*
2. That is **really** helpful -> That is helpful.
3. That will **definitely** meet your need -> That will meet your need

So are Grammarly's suggestions correct? When are those words **not** wordy?

--- update ---

For future readers, instead of voting to close it would you please help me to improve my question? The question is real for me and I don't know where else can I ask the question.

Comment: If you can leave them out and still mean the same thing, they're wordy. All they do is say you're serious, but you wouldn't be writing unless you were. In speech, they do a job representing your emotional state; but in writing that's not the point.

Comment: So you agree with Grammarly that in writing they are unnecessary.

Comment: No, merely that they are oral expressions that are often too unsophisticated for serious writing. Emphasis is one of the basic principles of rhetoric -- unity, coherence, and emphasis are all necessary. But there's lots of ways to emphasize something.

Comment: Can you put your two comments into an answer? It *really* helps! (lol)

Comment: They won't be any different in an answer. Just don't rely on Grammarly. Remember, anybody anywhere can say anything at all about English grammar, and somebody somewhere will believe them. That's one reason why we get so many silly questions here.

Comment: But as a non-native speaker and nobody to help me around, Grammarly is one of the few tools I can find. But yes I know don't  just rely on it, hence the question.

Comment: So it doesn't hafta be correct, just free, eh? Eventually a book might help.

Comment: No, I pay for the premium version so Grammarly can give more suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

When considered as simple statements, Grammarly gives reasonable advice about them.

But a full answer to your question may lie in meaning & context, and not in convention or over-simple grammatical dogma. Each of these words may be used to relate to a real or imagined comparison. Let me try some examples:

John: “*They lost because it was getting dark.*”
Susan: “*Basically, they lost because they did not practice.*”
In this example, Susan compares her reason with John’s and asserts that lack of practice was the fundamental reason for losing. They would have lost even if it had not gone dark.

“*Giving food is helpful but giving tools to grow food is really helpful.*”
The use of *really* emphasises the much greater help of tools. If we write “*giving food is helpful but giving tools to grow food is helpful*” the comparison is lost.

“*You may arrive on time if you take a bus but you will definitely arrive on time if you use this train*”.
This sets up a comparison of possibilities in which *definitely* focuses on the most likely one.

We have had a similar debate in Britain recently when one of our more prescriptive politicians told his staff not to use the emphatic "*very*". [Metro](https://metro.co.uk/2019/07/28/jacob-rees-mogg-falls-foul-style-guide-issued-staff-10473815/). Like Grammarly, his views are valid in some circumstances but are in general incomplete - even if not *very definitely really basically* wrong.

Comment: This was not a trivial question, and not one easily researched by a non-native speaker. I hope there is enough food for thought and discussion in my answer to justify non-closure.

Comment: Is it because I didn't give a full paragraph to be analysed so I have got 2 close votes ?

Comment: The two closers believe that the answer is a matter of opinion, not of fact. They are not saying that your question is wrong or incomplete. I therefore hope my own answer gives you reasons rather than mere opinion for the use or non-use of these words.

Comment: Your examples show where the "really" adverbs add to the meaning. The question examples do not.

Comment: Grammarly corrects my rushed spelling helpfully 4 out of 5 times. In grammar, less so, but it's still a reasonable challenge to me, allowing me to say I'm using X anyway.

Comment: Editing hack on opening a sentence with *basically*: Once you find a better way of phrasing something (and introduce it with "basically"), delete the previous sentence and the word "basically", too.